# Add a Macro Button to a Worksheet Using the Aspose.Cells API

Tags: excel, excel-2007, aspose, aspose-cells

How do I enable calling a macro on a button click via the Aspose.Cells API? I couldn't find any documentation on it. "Guessing" approach didn't yield any result either.

Comment: It is not possible with the current API. Please post on Aspose.Cells forums at http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx for details/confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Newer version support that:

http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Assign+Macro+to+Form+Control

Basically, you set the "MacroName" property, like so:

```
button.MacroName = sheet.Name + ".HelloWorld";
```